async loading with laravel+vite+alpinejs? (filamentphp custom field)
I'm trying to create a google maps class to use in a location clicker on laravel with filamentphp that uses alpine.js in conjunction with livewire.  Near as I can tell, I'm having problems with vite in laravel properly building my class and I'm not sure what I'm missing.
I saw somewhere that it wants ECMA type code so I converted my javascript (I think) to ECMA Script compatible format:
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

class Ccrmap {
    constructor(element, state, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.state = state;
        this.map = null;
        this.marker = null;
        this.options = {
            center: {
                lat: import.meta.env.MAP_CENTER_LAT,
                lng: import.meta.env.MAP_CENTER_LNG
            },
            zoom: import.meta.env.MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM,
            minZoom: import.meta.env.MAP_MIN_ZOOM,
            mapBounds: {
                north: import.meta.env.MAP_NORTH_BOUND,
                south: import.meta.env.MAP_SOUTH_BOUND,
                east: import.meta.env.MAP_EAST_BOUND,
                west: import.meta.env.MAP_WEST_BOUND
            }
        };

        this.loader = new Loader({
            apiKey: import.meta.env.GMAP_API,
            version: 'weekly',
            libraries: ['places', 'geometry', 'marker']
        });
    }

    initMapElement() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.element, {
            center: this.options.center,
            zoom: this.options.zoom,
            minZoom: this.options.minZoom,
            restriction: {
                latLngBounds: this.options.mapBounds,
                strictBounds: false
            },
            streetViewControl: false
        });
        this.map.addListener('click', (event) => {
            if(this.marker) {
                marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            } else {
                this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latLng,
                    map: map
                });
            }
            this.state = event.latLng.toJSON();
        });
    }

    initializeMap() {
        console.log('in initializeMap, loading Google Maps API', this.state);

        this.loader.importLibrary('maps')
            .then( () => this.initMapElement() )
            .catch(e => {
                console.error('Error loading Google Maps API', e);
            });
    }
}

export default Ccrmap;

From what examples I can find, I then created a wrapper around it as gmap-location.js:
import { Ccrmap } from './components/ccrmap.js';

window.Ccrmap = Ccrmap;

Then in a Custom Field component in laravel+filamentphp I created a gmap-location.blade.php with:
@php
    //$api_key = getenv('GMAP_API_KEY');
@endphp
<x-dynamic-component
    :component="$getFieldWrapperView()"
    :field="$field">
    <div
        x-data="{
        }"
        x-init="
            console.log({windowCcrmap: window.Ccrmap});
        "
        ax-load-src="[@js(\Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentAsset::getScriptSrc('gmap-location'))]"
        style="height: 400px; width: 50%;"
    >
        <div x-ref="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
</x-dynamic-component>

as an alternative I also tried x-load-js instead of ax-load-src but either way I do it Ccrmap is undefined, window.Ccrmap is undefined. However, if I go to the browser javascript console (presumably after the page has fully loaded) I do see a window.Ccrmap which points to an ulgiflied version of Ccrmap designated as 'L'
What do I need to do to get the map code to asyncronously load an initialize in a filamentphp custom field?
Additional info:
I eventually want to initialize a Ccrmap object in the alpine.js x-init. I was originally doing this inside the div but Ccrmap / window.Ccrmap undefined errors kept spitting out:
        x-data="{
            ccrmap: new Ccrmap($refs.map, $wire.$entangle('{{ $getStatePath() }}')),
        }"
        x-init="
            await ccrmap.initializeMap();
        "


I should add that gmap-location is registered in the AppServiceManager as ->loadedOnRequest()
